# What is the exact syntax format of "substitute this for that"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Substitute X for Y](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/substitute-x-for-y)

Many times people say "You want to substitute this for that?" What are they talking about putting in and what are they taking out. Is it based on context or the definition of *substitute*? Or is it just plain ambiguous, and are there less ambiguous ways of saying it?