# A was replaced by B. A was replaced. B was ____?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Background**

I was writing some comments in my code. There's a class that holds ID numbers for items that were replaced, and ID numbers for the items that replaced them.

Above the variable holding the old ID numbers, I wrote:

> The keys and ID numbers for the components that were replaced

I then began to write the corresponding comment for the other variable, holding the new ID numbers:

> The keys and ID numbers for the components that...

**Question**

When something has been replaced by something else, we can say those items were "replaced". Is there a corresponding past tense word to describe the items that they were replaced with?

Substituted maybe?

Basically, finish that second sentence as concisely as possible, in a manner as similar to the first as possible.

Comment: "that were the replacements" or "that replaced the old ones", perhaps?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yeah, you can clearly use a phrase that references the ones that were replaced. However, you don't need to reference the new ones to say that the old ones were replaced. I was just struck by yet another example of an apparent lack of symmetry in English.

Comment: What is wrong with *substituted*?

Comment: _B replaced A_. No "was"; it's active, not passive.

Comment: There's related stuff in [“Replace with” versus “replace by”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/) about how active/passive voice affects the *with/by* preposition choice. Basically, *Active voice favours **with**, Passive voice favours **by***.

Comment: @vladkornea I don't know that anything is *wrong* with 'substituted', it just didn't seem quite right. Also, I didn't think of it until I was about done writing the question.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't understand what you're trying to say. If B replaced A, then A was replaced. "A was replaced" is a complete sentence by itself.

Comment: _B replaced A. A was replaced by B. A was replaced._

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes... and?

Comment: Your question is flawed. There is no "B was .......". B is the agent, A is the patient, _was_ is the auxiliary for the passive, which makes the patient the subject. Agent subjects don't occur with passives. That's all.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sounds like you have something strange and interesting to say about this subject. I wouldn't mind seeing an answer challenging the frame of the question if you wouldn't mind writing one. That being said, neither B nor A is really the 'agent' here. *I'm* the agent. I replaced A with B. I did something to A, and I did something to B. 'Replaced' describes what happened to A. I'm just looking for a word to describe what happened to B.

Comment: Which depends on what it was. It may have been inserted, or it may have been rethreaded, or it may have fallen in. If you leave off the agent ***I*** from a passive, it becomes indistinguishable from the passive of a simple transitive _B replaced A_. Deletions always cause ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word ***emplace*** is suitable:

> : to put into position <missiles *emplaced* around the city>
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://i.word.com/idictionary/emplace)</sub>

Its use has been adopted by C++ to mean creating an element in a container without copying.

Comment: There we go, that's it. Nice find: The keys and ID numbers for the components that were emplaced.

Comment: I don't like this answer, because it does not convey that a replacement happened.

Comment: @Fax: This was an answer I provided for the OPs ask. I would probably use different wording instead of replacement, such as *current* and *previous* (ie, *The current keys and ID numbers* and *The previous keys and ID numbers*).

Answer (score 1):

> The keys and ID numbers for the components that were replaced
>
> The keys and ID numbers for the components that are the replacements

Probably. Or possibly:

> The keys and ID numbers for the new components

Depending on what you really mean by replacements.

Are they one for one replacements, i.e. there was a list [1, 2, 3] and you have replaced 1->5, 2->6 and 3->7 yielding [5, 6, 7]?

If so, your data structure would possibly be better served as a list of tuples anyway, and then you could say:

> The key and ID number replacement pairs

Or is there just a new list and you're listing the changes, i.e. [1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 6, 7] where the "replaced" list is [1,3] and the replacements are [5, 6, 7]?

If so, it might be clearer to say specifically:

> The keys and ID numbers for the components that were removed
>
> The keys and ID numbers for the components that were added

Comment: I upvoted, because it's essentially the answer I would have given, but I think the most apt phrasing is: **The keys and ID numbers for the replacement components** which doesn't actually appear on your list of options.

Answer (score 0):

Supersede

> take the place of (a person or thing previously in authority or use); supplant.

Comment: So: The keys and ID numbers for the components that superseded?

Comment: That's really just a synonym for replace. I could say ".. for the components that replaced" and it would sound equally awkward.

Comment: @DCShannon The keys and ID numbers for the components that *were* superseded by ___ are ___

Comment: The ones that were superceded are the old ones.

Comment: I like *supplant*.  *Supersede* means that something is officially designated to supplant something else.  When the replacement actually occurs, that is "supplanting".

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to mind was:

**["subbed in"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subbed_in)**

...the past participle of **'sub in'**

It sounds quite casual to my ears, but code comments are code comments :). It has been around for a while:

[image]

Comment: It **is** casual, because it's a shortening of *substitute/substituted*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *replace* is active, replaced is *passive*, so they lend themselves best to different constructions.   If you really want to maintain parallelism, however, then it's actually your first phrase which is best rewritten.  May I suggest

> The keys and ID numbers for the **replaced** components

and

> The keys and ID numbers for the **replacement** components

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, but still useful