# "Swap out with" or "Swap out for"? Also, can you specify a location after the word "out"?

Tags: grammar, idioms, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I've read articles online that use "*swap out with*," but many dictionaries seem to prefer "*swap out for*." Do they differ in meaning? Also, can you specify a location after the word "*out*"?

Consider the sentences below for example:

1.) *"Sean swapped the signed letter out [**of the steel drawer**] **with/for** the forged letter."*

2.) *"Sean swapped the youngest player out [**of the team**] **with/for** the more experienced one."*

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's exactly a duplicate, but ["Replace with" versus "replace by"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151309/replace-with-versus-replace-by) seems to cover much the same ground as this question.

Comment: _Out_ is not part of a phrasal verb.  The letter had been taken _out of_ the drawer, and the player _out of_ the team.

Comment: I'm good with *I swapped **out** the faulty drive* and *I swapped the faulty drive **for** a new one*. For no obvious reason, I wouldn't be so likely to include ***out*** in that second longer utterance, but it wouldn't bother me if someone else *did* include it. I'd say that in *those* examples, ***out*** is indeed part of a "phrasal verb" combination - but as Kate says, it's just a preposition in ***out** of the drawer / team*, and in *those* contexts I don't find it idiomatic to include a ***for-clause*** specifying what was swapped ***in*** as a replacement.

Comment: Thanks, Kate and FumbleFingers, for your insights! But should "swap out" be followed by "for" or "with"? Can we use either? Thanks!

Comment: To my my mind if you swap A _for_ B then you have removed B and left A in its place, however swapping A _with_ B means the opposite to me. I would say that _I_ might swap something with _someone else_ which would mean that the items swapped would be equivalent in some way (for example I might swap coats, or cars or houses with someone else) but I wouldn't use _with_ to describe the action of removing B and leaving A. The use of 'substitute' often seems to be reversed these days as well.  People say "substitute A for B" when they mean use B instead of A but that's the wrong way round to me.