# Is 'euphemism' definition by dictionary.com correct?

Tags: meaning

> [Euphemism - noun](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/euphemism?s=t)
>
> 1. the substitution of a mild, indirect, or vague expression for one thought to be offensive, harsh, or blunt.
> 2. the expression so substituted: “To pass away” is a euphemism for “to die.”.

Is this correct? "To pass away" is thought to be offensive, while "to die" is mild?

Comment: It's correct, you just have it backwards.  "To pass away" is less blunt than "to die".

Comment: Tom, you might like to look at [this page](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/substitute-x-for-y) ,which I think addresses your question.

Comment: @Margana the link explain "“Substitute…for…”—first replaces second; ok, but here it says "substitution **of**...for...", the substitution **of** is still the first replaces the second? Sounds really confusing for me... I understand that euphemism is to use a mild term, instead of a blunt one, but the dictionary definition looks like to say the oposite.

Comment: @Margana the answer from user39813 there is the best for me :)

Comment: @Tom: Ok. I think what's bothering you is the difference between the usage for a verb and that for a noun. As you say in your comment, both examples give "for", so they agree on that. The reason one uses "of" and not the other is that in: "To subsititue A for B", "substitute" is a verb. In "the substitution of A for B", "substitution" is a noun, which needs to be connected to its object with "of". So, "Substitute A for B" = "The substitution _of_ A for B". Is this helpful?

Comment: @z7sgѪ I apologise. I realise I have made the confusion worse by referring to the dictionary entry as though it was the OP's own wording. I am going to delete my comment as it is clearly not helpful. Your first comment is correct, and I have up-voted it.

Comment: @TomBrito - "A is a euphemism for B" means "A is a milder replacement for B."

Comment: @WS2 No worries, looks like OP is happy now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it mixed up. "To die" is considered blunt, while "To pass way" is considered a milder way of putting it (euphemism).