# Why is "substitute" used incorrectly in this sentence: "I would like to substitute the French fries with mashed potatoes"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, grammaticality

One frequently hears the verb "substitute" used in an incorrect backward fashion. For example, one may hear "I would like to substitute French fries with mashed potatoes" instead of the correct "I would like to substitute mashed potatoes for the French fries." "Substitute" always refers to the item or person being replaced. It's very hard to get people to see this distinction. If one were to use the word "exchange", it could be used either way, but "substitute" is directional, so to speak.

Comment: But you’ve also changed the ***with*** to ***for***, that changes the direction.

Comment: I think that this is an interesting question. In a similar vein, I have noticed frequent use of both "sub[stitute] out" and "sub[stitute] in" as verb phrases—meaning essentially the same thing as "swap out" and "swap in"—which may have some bearing on the popular sense that _substitute_ can function bidirectionally as a verb.

Comment: It isn't incorrect. It works the same as *exchange*, *swap*, or *trade*. You can exchange A for B, or you can exchange B with A. The choice usually revolves around focus. Do you particularly want something, or do you particularly not want something? Can I substitute the OEM oil filter with a generic that costs less? You could ask (but nobody does) "can I substitute a less costly generic filter for the OEM one?" High valence verbs with prepositional phrase arguments are pretty loose order-wise. Trading my A for your B is typical, but not mandatory. We could trade your B for my A instead.

Comment: It is not the same as _exchange_ in my opinion and that of most references. The Oxford English dictionary uses a faulty analogy in trying to draw a parallel between the nonstandard usage and sports usage for substituting a player. They do however admit that the looser usage leads to imprecision.

Comment: It is not I who changed the preposition from _for_  to  _with_; that is the construction of those who wish to use it in the backward sense.

Comment: There is a good related thread on this topic here - [substitute-x-for-y](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/substitute-x-for-y). Interestingly, a couple members point out that *replace* can sometimes be the compliment to *substitute*, as in *replace the fries with mashed potatoes*. This only works where the ideas a substitute/substitution is roughly the same as a replacement. In my world, they aren't. My choice of replace/substitute is governed by which one I'm after, A substitute part and a replacement part aren't the same thing. And I might need a substitute replacement part.

Comment: There is a good usage note on this in the [AHD article](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/substitute). The usage panel does not fully endorse your opinion.

Comment: The American Heritage Dictionary usage note reinforces my opinion, and the overwhelming majority of the usage panel disapproved of using "substitute" with the prepositions "with" or "by", in the reverse sense. They were more forgiving of its use that way in sports, although still slightly more disapproved. I think its use in sports like baseball is a relatively new back construction of the term "substitute (player)".

Answer (score 2):

This "incorrect" usage has been around for a long time.

The OED says:

> Use in this sense has been sometimes criticized (as with sense 3a), but is now generally regarded as part of normal standard English.

And their first citation for this sense is:

> 1839   tr. C. P. de Kock Barber of Paris I. iv. 92   I carried off a rabbit from the spit, and substituted it with the cat of my old aunt.

Comment: Also, from a [debate on relief to land purchases](https://books.google.com/books?id=0q5CAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA261&dq=%22Lowrie+moved+to+substitute+with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji1vPk8P3XAhVT6GMKHYCEBZUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Lowrie%20moved%20to%20substitute%20with%22&f=false) (February 2, 1821), in _Debates and Proceedings in the Congress of the United States_, volume 37: "This amendment Mr. LOWRIE moved to **substitute with** the deduction of _twenty-five_ per cent." (The bill had previously set the allowable discount at 37.5 percent.)

Comment: That just shows that the incorrect usage has been around for a while.

Comment: But this explains why people use it (if that was your question). They grew up hearing other people use it. That's the way language changes. A few people made a mistake 200 years ago, other people repeated it without realizing it was wrong, and today it's become an accepted usage of the word *substitute*.

Comment: In the words highlighted in the link I included in my comment above, _purchases_ should be _purchasers_.